# numpy fftn order of individual ffts

Tags: python, numpy, fft

fft2 and fftn provide the axis parameter which allows to specify over which axes to perform the transform. Does the method obey order?

Given a 2-dimensional numpy array

a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

is

```
fft2(a,axis=(0,1)
```

different from

```
fft2(a,axis=(1,0)
```

I have data which is correlated across lines but not columns...

Comment: As the FFT is linear and separable, the order of execution does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DFT is separable, which means calculating the 2D DFT is the same as calculating two individual 1D DFTs along each axis:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)

out1 = np.fft.fft2(a)

tmp = np.fft.fft(a, axis=0)
out2 = np.fft.fft(tmp, axis=1)

np.allclose(out1, out2) # True
```

And since the [nested summations of the DFTs commute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Multidimensional_DFT), the order of operations does not matter

```
tmp = np.fft.fft(a, axis=1)
out3 = np.fft.fft(tmp, axis=0)

np.allclose(out1, out3) # True
```

Which means the order of the `axes` parameter does not matter either

```
out4 = np.fft.fft2(a, axes=(1, 0))

np.allclose(out1, out4) # True
```